# Delete rows in one table with query in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my database.

table customer with ID,firstName,lastName,address...

and table orders with id, idCustomer...

and I want to delete all the orders of the customers where the first name is "john"

How I write the command?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE o
FROM        Orders   o
INNER JOIN  Customer c ON o.idCustomer = c.ID
WHERE       c.firstName = 'john'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete From
    orders 
Where
    Orders.firstName In 
        (Select
            firstName 
        From
            customers
            Inner Join orders On customers.ID = orders.idCustomer
        Where
            customers.firstName = "john")
```